# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'?

Tags: python, macos, github, terminal, lxml

Im working on a github project which is called `rabbit-escape`. Preferred operating system is Linux but Im trying to work on mac(Also developers say can work on mac but a little bit harder). So I cloned the project and downloaded prerequisites.

Prerequisites:  `You need Java, Git, Make, Sox, Inkscape and the standard Unix tools to be able to build the images, sounds and code.`

**My terminal error with `make test`:**

```
>>make test
. Checking for warnings in Makefile
. Checking version number (0.13.1) is consistent everywhere
. Checking for use of java.awt in engine code
. Generating animations list
. Generating level lists
. Converting images
.. rabbot bin/imagessvggen/rabbot_climb_left_continue_09.svg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build-scripts/rabbit-to-rabbot", line 11, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'
make: *** [images.mk] Error 1
```

**In addition:**

`>>from lxml import etree
from: can't read /var/mail/lxml`

Sorry if its duplicate but I tried many preferred solutions and could not find the exact way that is why created my own topic.

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3-lxml doesn't work?

Comment: If im not wrong mac does not use apt-get command

Comment: Try installing from pypi with `pip install lxml`

Comment: Says this: `Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (4.4.1)`

Comment: Maybe i need to add a path ?

Comment: Do you run the code with Python 2.7 or another version?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand the question. In rabbit-escape directory im trying to run `make compile` and `make test`.

Comment: try to install lxml for python3. `pip3 install lxml` If the `make` command uses the python3 interpreter, you need to install `lxml` for python3. But you installed the python2 version.